# Android : How to restrict parent container's setclipchildren(false) property to be applicable only for one child

Tags: android, animation

In my app, there is a layout (root_layout) which contains child layout(layout1) inside a scroll view. This layout1 contains a list of items. And, area of the layout1 is fixed. Items in the layout1 scrolls within this area.

Structure is as follows :

```
<RelativeLayout>
  <ScrollView>
     <LinearLayout>
        <ListView/>
     </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, I want that when I click on any of the list items, translation animation should apply to it which will move the item outside the layout1 and the top right corner of the screen.
As in android , by default it can only move within its parent container area. So, I have set the "android:clipchildren" property of all (root layout, layout1 and scroll view) to "false" which allows the item to move outside its container.

But then, the other items in the list are also appearing outside its container area.
I want to restrict other items to remain in its boundaries.

Is there a way so that we can allow only one child to move outside its boundaries and the behavior of other items remain unchnaged ?